# How to get only the values from the file while parsing it?

Tags: python

I am parsing a config file I would like to get only the values which are file paths in the file

for example the config file has

```
apache.access =  /var/log/apache2/access.log
apache.errors = /var/log/apache2/errors.log
```

I would like to get only '/var/log/apache2/access.log' and '/var/log/apache2/errors.log' from the

```
COMMENT_CHAR = '#'
OPTION_CHAR =  '='



def parse_config(filename):
    options = {}
    f = open(filename)
    for line in f:
        if COMMENT_CHAR in line:
           line, comment = line.split(COMMENT_CHAR, 1)
        if OPTION_CHAR in line:
            option, value = line.split(OPTION_CHAR, 1)
            option = option.strip()
            value = value.strip()
            options[option] = value
    f.close()
    return options
```

I tried this but it gives all the options and values in the file

apache.access :  /var/log/apache2/access.log

apache.errors : /var/log/apache2/errors.log

Comment: Are you searching for `options.values()`?

Comment: yes I have the values but some values are file paths and some are not 
I want to have only the values which are file paths

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to define, **what** is a file path (1. does it have to exist? 2. does it have to be creatable in an existing directory? 3. anything else?). This tests whether the given string is a path pointing to an existing dir/file:

```
import os

# ...

[v for v in options.itervalues() if os.path.exists(v)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions is what you need. Here is little example how it could look

```
import re

f = open("apache.log")
for line in f:
    m = re.match("apache\.(access|errors)\s+=\s+(.+)", line)
    if None != m:
        print (m.group(2))
f.close()
```